# Node.js, Async, and Socket.on/.once events

Tags: node.js

So the issue I'm currently running into, is I have to events in my little node.js project.

```
Socket.once('data', function (data) {
//a login function that handles user names
});
```

And a second event

```
    Socket.on('data', function (data) {
 //function that lets user chat

});
```

My issue is when I run it, and a client connects, this happens.

```
"Please Login"
*Client inputs login*
Your name is "Billtest"
Billtest says "Billtest"
Billtest says "Hi, that wasn't suppose to happen"
```

Basically, both functions end up running and getting the same input.

I want my Socket.once event to run first, and my Socket.on event to only run after the socket.once event has finished.

I tried figuring this out on my own, but I guess with no clear way to put it, I don't understand any of it.  I've looked over promises and async and everything, but I never seem to be able how exactly to implement it with my functions.

Is it even possible? If so could some give me a more precise example on how to implement async functions so they run sequentially? Instead of all at once? I've gone over the MDN and googled for the last couple days, but the examples I find don't seem to really explain in detail, how to set this up.

I tried an if statement using userName === undefined, but both functions end up running still.

And I just can't seem to wrap my ahead around any other solution I've looked at.

Answer (score 0):

Hi why not just think of easy solution? Using different event name

```
// event 'user-join' handles first username thing
Socket.once('user-join', function (data) {
    //a login function that handles user names
});

// event 'chat' handles chat message
Socket.on('chat', function (data) {
    //function that lets user chat
});
```

When you emit, you do `socket.emit('user-join', data)`

Comment: Sadly I think the Library I'm using for invoking event.js and net.js requires/expects a 'data'.  Also even I changed the named of my Socket.once, data didn't get passed into the function so all my user names came out as undefined... and it still ran the socket.on event lol.    I wish I could go deeper, but my code is tied into the ranvier-telnet module because it is in fact, a telnet server.

Answer (score 0):

[Async](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) is a good choice for similar problems. In your case, `async.waterfall` or `async.series` functions should do the job.

```
async.series([
    function(callback) {
        // your login function
        callback(null, 'one');
    },
    function(callback) {
        // your chat function
        callback(null, 'two');
    }
],
function(err, results) {
    // results is now equal to ['one', 'two']
});
```

Comment: this causes the same output.  Both my socket.once event and my socket.on event get the data the time.